# Keeping Javascript reference after setting the reference to something else

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have

```
var myFirstArray = [{letter: 'a'}, {letter: 'b'}, {letter: 'c'}];
```

I would like to make a reference to myFirstArray, so I do this:

```
var mySecondArray = myFirstArray;
```

Pushing, splicing, modifying elements in myFirstArray will be shown in mySecondArray, but if I want to reset that array to something else:

```
myFirstArray = [];
```

or

```
myFirstArray = someOtherData;
```

My reference is lost. I understand why this is, but I want `mySecondArray` to point at whatever `myFirstArray` is pointing at, at any time. What's the best way to do this?

My workarounds include:

```
// Just empty the array and push it:
while (myFirstArray.length) myFirstArray.pop(); 
for (var x in data) myFirstArray.push(x);

// Or put the array in an object:
var viewBag = {};
viewBag.myFirstArray = [...];

var mySecondArray = viewBag.myFirstArray;
```

I dislike both of these options :(

**Edit**: Consider another scenario:

```
function doSomethingToMyArray (theArray) {
  // Say I get new data that will be formatted the way I want it to be
  // Shouldn't I be allowed to do this? 

  var myNewData = [{ letter: 'd' }];
  theArray = myNewData;
}

var myFirstArray = [{letter: 'a'}, {letter: 'b'}, {letter: 'c'}];

doSomethingToMyArray (myFirstArray);

// At this point, myFirstArray will still be a, b, c instead of d
```

Comment: `myFirstArray.length = 0;` will clear your Array for both, if that's all that you need to do. If you wish to totally replace the contents then: `myFirstArray.length = 0; myFirstArray.push.appy(myFirstArray, someOtherData);`. These will both affect `mySecondArray` as well, provided you're made it reference `myFirstArray` as your question implies.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have variable references. It only has references to objects and arrays.

Comment: Barmar, ok -- so are you saying there is no way to keep a reference Foo to an array / object Bar when Bar points to a new array / object?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set mySecondArray whenever you set myFirstArray?

A good tip for setting variables quickly is this syntax:

```
var mySecondArray, myFirstArray;

mySecondArray = myFirstArray = ["somevalue"];
```

In JavaScript, when you set myFirstArray to something like [], and then mySecondArray to myFirstArray, it won't reference the first variable, but both variables will reference the same actual array.

Comment: If you're going to set both variables all the time, what's the point of having two variables?

Comment: That is true, Greg Pete, why do you need two variables?

Comment: Thanks TRGWII, but the reason is that I am using Angular, and a parent scope owns myFirstArray while a child scope owns mySecondArray -- I want to minimize cross controller communication for these arrays if possible (even if it's through a service or through $watch). mySecondArray must be the same as myFirstArray but uses a different name because it is the name of the variable that a template (which mySecondArray's controller controls) is using.

Comment: Hmm, this might not be clean enough, how about a tiny function?
`mySecondArray = { get: function(){ return myFirstArray; } };`

then you could use:
`mySecondArray.get()`
whenever you need to reference it from mySecondArray's controller.

(Might want to change the name of mySecondArray for readability)

Comment: TRGWII - That's a good workaround for the first scenario I laid out. However, what about the second scenario where I am trying to set the array to a new dataset within another method?

Comment: That would only set a local variable called theArray within the function, try this instead:

`function doSomethingToMyArray(theArray){
  ...
  return myNewData;
}`

And then use `myFirstArray = doSomethingToMyArray(myFirstArray)`

Answer (score 0):

What is happen is that when you set the parent variable to a new value, the watchers are lost and the changes aren't applied to the child.

You need to do this extremely obnoxious convention of putting the file in a data map.

So, instead of:

var myFirstArray

Use:

$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.myFirstArray = blah;

I highly recommend giving the data object a smarter name is possible.

Another problem you could be experiencing is the "dot problem", [which is explained in this blog post.](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/)

Comment: Thanks. While I am using Angular, this is more of a regular Javascript issue. See my edit on the question to demonstrate the issue.